Serverless S3 Sync is invalid
I was getting started with serverless everything was fine until i used S3Sync to upload data to my bucket, this is my yml file i also installed serverless-s3-sync plugin using yarn before using sls deploy.
service: iamserverless
app: AnshFamily

plugins:
  - serverless-s3-sync
  
custom:
  s3Sync:
    - BucketName: kfchickenbucket-699
      localDir: S3

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x



functions:
  hello:
    handler: lambda/handler.Family



resources:
  Resources:
    FamilyBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: kfchickenbucket-699`

i went through the serverless docs but its the same steps i followed. So pls help!
error-
Deploying "iamserverless" to stage "dev" (us-east-1)
Excluding development dependencies for service package
✖ Stack iamserverless-dev failed to deploy (20s)
✖ Invalid custom.s3Sync
error-console-image

Please include the exact error message and what you did that produces the error.

Deploying "iamserverless" to stage "dev" (us-east-1)
Excluding development dependencies for service package
✖ Stack iamserverless-dev failed to deploy (20s)
✖ Invalid custom.s3Sync

See the documentation for the plugin. The config property is bucketName, but you have BucketName.
custom:
  s3Sync:
    - bucketName: kfchickenbucket-699
      localDir: S3

